# Solr: How to upgrade solrcloud 5.5.1 to 6.6.0

Tags: linux, solr, centos, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I want to upgrade the solrcloud to the newest version in CentOS.IS there have a step by step to do this process. and I don't want to loose my indexes also.

Answer (score 0):

Lets answers your question by taking example. Assume that below is your Solr Cloud structure.

- Shard1

  - node1 (20 docs) (5.5.1)
  - node2 (20 docs) (5.5.1)
- Shard2

  - node3 (20 docs) (5.5.1)
  - node4 (20 docs) (5.5.1)

**Now you will add a replica to both of the shards.

First you add two nodes to Zookeeper. But this both nodes will be of Solr 6.6.0.**

```
bin/solr start -cloud -s /Users/XYZ/Downloads/solr-6.5.0/example/cloud/node6/solr -p 8957 -z localhost:9983
```

Add one replica to Both shards

```
localhost:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=ADDREPLICA&collection=collectionName&shard=shard1
localhost:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=ADDREPLICA&collection=collectionName&shard=shard2
```

After adding replicas your Solr Cloud Structure will look like :-

- Shard1

  - node1 (20 docs) (5.5.1)
  - node2 (20 docs) (5.5.1)
  - node5 (20 docs) (6.6.0)
- Shard2

  - node3 (20 docs) (5.5.1)
  - node4 (20 docs) (5.5.1)
  - node6 (20 docs) (6.6.0)

Remove node1, node2, node3 and node4. Your cloud structure will be in Solr 6.6.0.

Comment: Hi Sanjay Sorry for the late reply.
I am new for solr and i got the task to upgrade the solr 5.5.1 to  solr 6.6.0. in my server have tomcat8 folder and solr home folder i really dont know how to do this task. bcz i want to learn from the beginning to do all this.but i don't have much time. IS it possible to help on this to do step by step.